# example of monkey test for music application using wifi

Tags: android, sdk, monkeyrunner

All:

I am working on Android Music Application which is using WiFi. I would like to know what kind of test script/ monkey runner that some of you would like to recommend. Sample monkey script or monkey runner is welcomed.

Thanks in advance,

Droigons

Comment: Start with something and then post the code and any question/problem you may find.